# No error messages on phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am using the latest version (4.4.12) of phpMyAdmin. 
When I am trying to run an invalid mysql command in the "SQL"-Tab of a database or table phpmyadmin returns no error messages.

For example I try:

```
CREATE VIEW test (a, b c) AS SELECT "A" as a, "B" as b, "C" as c
```

(notice the missing comma after "b"!) 
Running this malformed command phpMyAdmin returns an success message (the "green check mark") and a message, that mysql returns zero datasets - which is correct for an CREATE command.

It seems, that phpmyadmin did not check for mysql errors or did not return them.

I had the same problem with an older version (4.4.3)

Is it a bug or do I have a misconfiguration?

Edit: I found out, that it sometime(!) works, if I send the SQL twice, but only on complex queries. The example above still don't throw an error if I send it twice.

Another example:
INSERT INTO `test` (a, b c) VALUES (1, 2, 3);
(also missing comma after "b") 
Returns: "OK -1 rows inserted. (Query took 0.0009 seconds.)"

So, -1 must be an error. But phpMyAdmin returns the green checkmark and not an error.

my config.inc.php:

```
<?php
/*
 * Generated configuration file
 * Generated by: phpMyAdmin 4.4.12 setup script
 * Date: Thu, 23 Apr 2015 13:25:48 +0200
 */

/* Servers configuration */
$i = 0;

/* Server: localhost [1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'socket';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['nopassword'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking_version_auto_create'] = true;

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

/* End of servers configuration */

$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '5538d3a45e6924.68498003';
$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'de';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
$cfg['CheckConfigurationPermissions'] = false;
$cfg['AllowArbitraryServer'] = true;
$cfg['LoginCookieDeleteAll'] = false;
$cfg['UserprefsDeveloperTab'] = true;
$cfg['DBG']['sql'] = true;

$cfg['MaxRows'] = 500;
$cfg['Order'] = 'DESC';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

By running this invalid mysql  command in **phpMyAdmin** :

```
CREATE VIEW test (a, b c) AS SELECT "A" as a, "B" as b, "C" as c
```

I get the fallowing error message :

```
errors were found during analysis.

        A comma or a closing bracket was expected (near "c" at position 23)
```

so it only your version that have this problem , reinstall it or reset the setting .

Comment: Same problem after reinstallation..I've added my config.inc.php to the question

Comment: Nobody any idea why this problem causes?